# Microsoft Graph access token for single user within Outlook add-in

Tags: azure, outlook, outlook-addin, microsoft-graph-api

Is there is a way to get Microsoft Graph access token from Azure AD within Outlook add in? Technically user is logged in when Outlook is open, so from outlook add in I can get email ID (internetMessageId https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook&version=v1.5), username, etc.

I want to use email id and token to retrieve single email message https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_get

But is it possible to generate Azure AD access token not making the user log in once again like in the example? https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js

Cheers

Comment: by the way, can this be a valid sample? https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers#authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain a token for using with Graph/Outlook REST APIs using the [Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook&version=v1.5) method introduced in Mailbox 1.5.

There is a walkthrough of this in the docs: [Use the Outlook REST APIs from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api).

Comment: thank you! Almost everything is working :) although I got empty value from my `Office.context.mailbox.restUrl` property and if it replacing it with default `https://outlook.office.com` request returning `400 Bad Request` Will research, guess some manifest issue.

Comment: Exact error is `RequestBroker-ParseUri` (`Resource not found for the segment 'messages`)

Comment: Are you by chance using a local Exchange 2016 server rather than Exchange Online? There is a note in the [docs](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook&version=v1.5#resturl-string) about this scenario not being supported.

Comment: @marc-lafleur-msft indeed,  I should pay attention! So I must find out my local rest url...